# <hr> disappears on CSS transform: scale()

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble with CSS right now and I can't figure out how to fix it. Basically I have a bootstrap cards which scale in on hover using a CSS class. Thing is, on hover and when it scales in, some of the `<hr>` I have in my card disappear, even though their CSS isn't changing at all. It seems to be a browser issue as it works perfectly on Safari but not on Chrome.
You may try it at this URL: https://lereseauglt.fr (scroll to the second slide & after on the card carousels and hover the cards).
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="card scaleIn">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row w-100 m-0">
            <div class="col-auto">[content]</div>
            <div class="col">[content]</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row w-100 m-0">
            <div class="col-auto">[other content]</div>
            <div class="col">[other content]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.scaleIn 
{
    transition:all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.scaleIn:hover 
{
    transform:scale(1.007);
    cursor:pointer;
}
hr {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

So my question is : is there any way to fix this weird effect?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest you rather then using `hr` use `border-top: 1px solid #ededed` on paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue occurs because of the `zoom: 80%` property of the element with ID `containerCours`.
Use the DevTools and notice how the zoom affects the border top width of the `hr` element - you expect it to be 1px, but it actually is 0.996px. Then on hover you scale the card inside the already zoomed container and the `hr` seems lost, but it is actually there. The top border of the element is so thin, that it is not visible. You can try to update the top border width of the `hr` to be 1.2px and it will be visible - check again the DevTools and notice that the top border width is 1.191px.

I would recommend you refactor the container zooming logic, because otherwise you will have to work with such uncertain floating-point units.

Comment: Great eye Dimitar. I'll work another way around this. Thanks a lot for the help!